# Why are .NET target framework defines not set?

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessor-directive, target-platform

The [Target Frameworks documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) cites that certain defines are automatically set based on the project's target framework, which I am assuming would change based on the `Target framework` field in `Properties > Application`:
[image]

Or when selecting the Target framework while creating a new Visual C# project (New Project > Visual C# > Console App (.NET Framework))

However as far as I've tested, none of the defines specified in the documentation are actually defined.

For example, If I create a `.NET Framework 3.5` project or manually set an existing project to target `.NET Framework 3.5` in properties, `NET35` is not defined.

I've taken every single define listed on the documentation page and added debug code that prints if any or all are defined, and none appear to be defined:
[image]
Sourcecode: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/ece8987fa18b2eaf830d7426c2256d6b

---

Am I making an incorrect assumption about when or how these defines should be set? What other portable way would I to conditionally compile code based on the target framework on a per-line basis?

I am running Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.8.4 with the default Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03056

Comment: Someone already has filed a bug report about this (https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/7096). Whether this is actually a bug or only available in certain/recent/new build systems, i don't know...

Answer (score 1):

No. Such predefined constants would only work if you work on the new SDK project format, and with multiple target frameworks (`net45` and `netstandard1.3` for example). Their existence is to help you perform conditional compilation so as to support multiple frameworks. [My blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0) shows a concrete example.

So you should create a new project that uses the new format, while .NET Framework Console Application template is not.

Answer (score 0):

In console application doesn't work but with window application if you remove from reference: the Microsoft.CSharp and System.Net.http